# Manual shortcut keys without using settings

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-manager, gconf

I want to change the "Close Window" shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> as this is more intuitive to me than the default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. Prior to 12.04 upgrade, I was just able to change this via the settings window, but in 12.04 when I try to set it as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> by pressing the keys for the settings manager to capture, it just closes the window and doesn't set the shortcut.

I have had a look through `gconf-editor`, but can't seem to find anything. Is there any way to manually set the shortcut key?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work when trying to set '+q' is because that combination is set for closing `System Settings` window. I would advise on not changing the keybinding for closing windows to '+q' as it should work for almost every application you open (I tried it on a few applications myself and it worked without me binding the keys to it).

If you still want to change it, I found this command to work the best:

`gconftool-2 -s /apps/metacity/window_keybindings/close -t string "<keybinding here>"`

For example, if you wish to change the close binding to control+q, then you would do the following:

`gconftool-2 -s /apps/metacity/window_keybindings/close -t string "<Control>q"`

Go into `System Settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts` and look for the 'Window Close' binding which should now read `Ctrl+Q`

Hope this helps.